# Time profiling C program with OSX Instruments 7.2

Tags: c, macos, profiling, instruments

I am using OSX El Capitan and Instruments 7.2. I want to time profile a very simple C program, just to get around Instruments environment.
As you can see in the picture attached, for some reason, Instruments provides information regarding the inner OS functions, but no information regarding the functions I used in my program, nor reference to the source code of the program.

This is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo();
int bar();
int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

int foo()
{
    bar();
    return 0;
 }

int bar()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Complied using:
gcc -g -Wall 123.c -o 123

[Instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eRHD.png)

Comment: The functions (except `main`) have differing signatures. Use correct prototypes.

Comment: And don't post external links or images of text in general.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment I don't have an option to embed pictures and thus it posts a link automatically. Regarding the prototypes, where do you see the mismatch?

Comment: I don't know Instruments, but: If your functions don't do much (which they do), they won't show up in any profiling information. Their CPU time will just vanish in the background noise of the C startup code and OS. Add some code that actually does something.

Comment: Hi tofro, following your advice I added some CPU consuming code. It did increase the CPU usage graph but the functions symbols are still missing from the Call Tree view...

Comment: BTW, if I go in the menu bar of Instruments to Instrument->Call Tree Data Mining->Locate dSYM... and provide it with the path of 123.dSYM file, I receive a "The UUID of '/Users/***/Desktop/123.dSYM' does not match the UUID for 'dyld'" error. I am not sure, but I have a feeling that the error might be related to the issue.

Comment: Read my comment carefully again! You are not supposed to post images of text **in general**. Paste the text as text iny our question!

Comment: Hi Olaf, the main issue I had was merely with the Instruments UI and less with the text. Thus I believe that the picture I attached has an added value since it demonstrates the issue brightly and simply.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, playing around with Instruments I found a way to overcome this issue. Simply by pressing on the Display Settings icon (looks like a mechanical wheel) on the right pane.
This open ups a window with a data mining table, there, any function that appears as "charged" or "pruned" can be restored back to the Call Tree view.

Once main was restored to Call Tree view, foo & bar appeared also, along with the matching source code.